# What is the correct formalization of the following mathematical statement about prime numbers in a predicate logic notation?

Tags: predicate-logic

I have to formalize the following mathematical statement in a predicate logic in a language L = {+, *, 0, 1, <} :

"There are infinitely many prime numbers"

I have found the following formalization but it is not clear to me why there is a necesity to embed another variable $d$ inside the formula. Formalization is the following:

$(\forall x)(\exists y)[x < y \land (\forall d)((\exists p)(p * d = y)\rightarrow (d = 1 \vee d = y))]$

Is it possible to write instead this? If not, why?:

$(\forall x)(\exists y)[x < y \land ((\exists p)(p * x = y)\rightarrow (x = 1 \vee x = y))]$

Comment: Start formalizing the [property "$n$ is *prime*"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1575465/peano-arithmetic-how-would-this-formalized-statement-be-correct).

Comment: Well I know that I can formalize the property "n is prime" the following way: $(\forall d)((\exists p)(p*d = y)\rightarrow (d=y \vee d=1))$ . Is that correct?

Comment: I would like to know especially, if I can write this:
$(\forall x)(\exists y)[x < y \land ((\exists p)(p * x = y)\rightarrow (x = 1 \vee x = y))]$ instead of this: $(\forall x)(\exists y)[x < y \land (\forall d)((\exists p)(p * d = y)\rightarrow (d = 1 \vee d = y))]$ . If not, why?

Comment: IMO, what you are trying to write is $\forall x \exists y (x < y \land \text {Prime}(y))$.

Comment: If,so, you have to replace the predicate $\text {Prime}(y)$ with the formula : $\forall n,m (y=n \cdot m \to (n=1 \lor n=y))$.

Comment: Is there a way to explain, why we have to create another variable $d$ instead of using already used variable $x$? Both variables have the quantifier $\forall$ and therefore it seems to me that it is not necessary to create another variable $d$ and instead I could use $x$.